# Dagger for first footnote on author field

Tags: symbols, footnotes

How can I get a dagger as the footnote symbol for the author field, not increment the counter, and start off at one with arabic characters from then on?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols{mySymbols}{{\ensuremath\dagger}{\ensuremath\ddagger}\S\P
   *{**}{\ensuremath{\dagger\dagger}}{\ensuremath{\ddagger\ddagger}}}
\setfnsymbol{mySymbols}

\begin{document}
\author{foo\thanks{bar}\thanks{a}\thanks{b}\thanks{B}\thanks{d}\thanks{a}\thanks{a}
}
\title{baz} 
\maketitle

\end{document}
```